# Accessing socket data in HTMLUNIT

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, htmlunit

In and normal Java Socket class you have the method public int getLocalPort() to find out what your source port is. Does anyone know how to access this information with HTMLUNIT?

Comment: Can you formulate more descriptive question?

Comment: how can I find out what the local outgoing socket is using HTMLUNIT as can be done with Java's Socket.getLocalPort()?

Answer (score 0):

```
currentPage.getUrl().getPort();
```

gives the port number of the URL being visited if that is what you are looking for.